# How do I achieve this 'dynamic cracking" effect in 2.8?

Tags: animation, modifiers, dynamic-paint

Im trying to achieve this effect in 2.8, any help would be great!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05tEg_Im6Bk

Comment: The Cell Fracture add-on exists in 2.8+ too. In what part of the process are you stuck ?

Comment: I missed the part where he joined all the cells together which is where I was stuck. I got it down, is there a way to enable physics on this? The cells are all one object now so Im wondering how I would go about running a simulation with physics enabled?